# iphone - model dialog box for UIbutton action

Tags: iphone

how can i show modal dialog box for UIbutton action.This model dialog box has only the UIPicker.

Thanks,
sam.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible. You could create a subview to use as an alert view.

Comment: how can i add a UIPickerView to UIAlertView

Comment: what i did I create a ModalView and add the UIPicker for that,now when i click the button it's loading the ModalView. Now i need to know how to pass the selected value to parent and close the ModalView

Comment: Set the ModalView's delegate to the parent class. Then the parent class will receive messages from the ModalView's actions.